# How can I enable "transparent data encryption" on all databases in a Azure DB pool?

Tags: azure-sql-database, tde, azure-elasticpool, elastic-database-pool

We have a couple of Azure Elastic database pool with hundreds of databases. Now we want to enable the Transparent Data Encryption feature. It is not a server or a pool setting, but a database setting.
It would cost me a day clicking in the portal to enable the TDE for all individual databases. Is there a smarter way of doing this? Scripting or multi selecting, or something like that?
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All newly created SQL databases are encrypted by default using service-managed TDE. Existing databases before May 2017 and databases created through restore, geo-replication, and database copy are not encrypted by default. For more information, please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-azure-sql) documentation.

You can create an elastic job to perform an ALTER DATABASE SET ENCRYPTION OFF for all databases on a pool. Read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/saas-tenancy-schema-management).

Comment: Thank you Alberto. I'll look into the elastic job.

Comment: Elastic pools + elastic jobs is way to go to ease management. Glad you find it may fit in your scenario.